# Why would you need to null coalesce a static member initialization?

Tags: javascript, singleton, mixpanel

I'm looking through the [Mixpanel for React Native example project](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-react-native/blob/master/MixpanelDemo/Analytics.js) and they're initializing a singleton like this:

```js
import {Mixpanel} from 'mixpanel-react-native';
import {token as MixpanelToken} from './app.json';

export default class MixpanelManager {
    static sharedInstance = MixpanelManager.sharedInstance || new MixpanelManager();

    constructor() {
        this.configMixpanel();
    }
    
    configMixpanel = async () => {
        this.mixpanel = await Mixpanel.init(MixpanelToken);
    }
}
```

I've never seen a singleton handled quite this way.  What's the circumstance where `MixpanelManager.sharedInstance` will already be set when this class gets declared?

Comment: This makes no sense indeed. The author probably mixed up some old singleton patterns.

Comment: The assignment to the static property will ensure that no more than one singleton will be created.

Comment: @Bergi I can't tell, but that's exactly the same code as on the "example" page linked.